# C++ weird looping

Tags: c++, loops

I wrote this function. While debugging, I saw that at the very end of the function, it goes to the `string cmonth[]` declare then back to the very end of the function, then back to the `string cmonth[]` declare, about 10 times. Then it goes back to the very first line of the function then back to the very last line of the function about 100 times or more.

```
int CheckLastDate(string file)
{
string line, dline[200];
int i = 0;
regex rxdate("[[:digit:]].:[[:digit:]].:[[:digit:]].");
ifstream infile;
infile.open(file.c_str());

if(! infile.is_open()) return -1;

while (infile.good())
{
    getline(infile, line);
    if(regex_search(line, rxdate))
    {
        dline[i] = line;
        i++;
    }
}
i--; //needed b/c dline starts at 0;
infile.close();

int imonth, day, hour, min, sec, year;
string month, ampm;
string cmonth[] = {"Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec" };

month = dline[i].substr(5,3);
//convert month to number
for(int j = 0; j<12; j++)
{
    if(month == cmonth[j]) imonth=j+1;
}

day = atoi(dline[i].substr(9, 2).c_str());
hour = atoi(dline[i].substr(12, 2).c_str());
min = atoi(dline[i].substr(15, 2).c_str());
sec = atoi(dline[i].substr(18, 2).c_str());
ampm = dline[i].substr(21, 2);
year = atoi(dline[i].substr(24, 4).c_str());

if(ampm == "PM" && hour != 12) { hour += 12; } //turn into 24 hours
else if(ampm == "AM" && hour == 12) { hour = 0; }

time_t now, dif; //dif = date in file
double diff;
time(&now);
struct tm * timeinfo;
timeinfo = localtime(&now);
timeinfo->tm_mon = imonth - 1;
timeinfo->tm_mday = day;
timeinfo->tm_hour = hour;
timeinfo->tm_min = min;
timeinfo->tm_sec = sec;
timeinfo->tm_year = year - 1900;
timeinfo->tm_isdst = -1; //-1 = no info
dif = mktime(timeinfo);
diff = difftime(now, dif);

if(diff >= 86400) return 1; //more then 24 hours
else return 0;
}
```

Is there something wrong, or is it how C++ works? 
Thank You for your help.

Comment: That's probably the destructor calls.

Comment: Are you sure you built the correct source? If the source doesn't match the compiled program (i.e. you made updates but not compiled it) then a debugger will appear to do very weird things.

Comment: Maybe you are debugging with optimizations turned on? Or debugging in 'release mode'? Optimizations do strange things to the code making it hard to debug.

Comment: Can you elaborate on which compiler and debugger you are using so others might be able to reproduce it?

Comment: I am debugging in debug mode. Also, I am debugging at C++ -code level.

Comment: @vis.15: OK you're in debug mode, but maybe you have optimizations turned on anyway. Check your project settings. Also it's always worth deleting the intermediate files and rebuilding from scratch.

Comment: I did the project settings, I didn't see anything about optimizations. I will try rebuilding from scratch. Rebuilt it from scratch, still did it.

Comment: Well maybe Mat is right. Something weird to do with boost::regex perhaps. If you look at the disassembled code at the end of your function you may get more of a clue.

Comment: @Martin Sorry I saw now saw your comment. I am using g++. I am also using NetBeans, and NetBeans uses these options while debugging: `-g -MMD -MP -MF`.

Comment: Can you provide us with a working example? It seems to be a strange enough problem that this might be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

It looks ok but some general pointers:

your for loop checking for the month goes through all months even when it finds the month,
that seems unnecessary.

you should acquire the habit of always initializing all variables. in debug mode variables may be initialized but in release mode they are normally not.

you should add some checks to make sure that the string that regex returns has the format that you expect. e.g. check length. You could also use `strtok_s()` to take the string apart if the tokens are delimited with spaces. it may be safer than expect that a token always has a certain length or is at a specific index.

when you read in from the file there is no check to prevent an error if the file has more than 200 lines. you should consider this. e.g. `while (infile.good() && i < 200)`

Comment: this is the type of string I am taking apart: "Thu, Aug 02 12:56:43 AM 2012 EDT"

Comment: Also, I am using Debian Linux with Boost (just for regex).

Answer (score 0):

Was it a debug or release build? Also, did you debug at C++ -code level, or assembler level?

In release builds the compiler may generate various code jumps not present in the initial function.

Comment: I am debugging in debug mode. Also, I am debugging at C++ -code level.